# Antipattern error when react child component updating parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am getting the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. How do I eliminate this recursive function in my child (`Typewriter`) component? I believe I am getting this error because I am calling a function constantly in the ComponentWillUpdate() ? How do I fix this? I thought that by adding in the if condition, this should be fixed?
 Please see the snippet below. Thanks!

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      typing: true,
    };
    this.interval = null;
    this.handleTyping = this.handleTyping.bind(this);
  }

  handleTyping(doneTyping) {
    if (doneTyping) {
      this.setState({ typing: !this.state.typing });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.typing ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</h3>
        <Typewriter text={"typewriter_testing"} typeSpeed={50} handleTyping={this.handleTyping}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Typewriter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      finalText: '',
      doneTyping: false,
    }
    this.typeWriter = this.typeWriter.bind(this);
  }

  typeWriter(text, n) {
    if (n < (text.length)) {
      if (n + 1 == (text.length)) {
        let j = text.substring(0, n+1);
        this.setState({ finalText: j, doneTyping: !this.state.doneTyping });
        n++;
      }
      else {
        let k = text.substring(0, n+1) + '|';
        this.setState({ finalText: k });
        n++;
      }
      setTimeout( () => { this.typeWriter(text, n) }, this.props.typeSpeed );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.typeWriter(this.props.text, 0);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.doneTyping) {
      nextProps.handleTyping(nextState.doneTyping);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.finalText }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: check my answer below please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this component need to run `nextProps.handleTyping(nextState.doneTyping);` on exact time when `doneTyping` is changed only.
add another condition in `componentWillUpdate` and check it out:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.doneTyping && (nextState.doneTyping !== this.state.doneTyping)) {
      nextProps.handleTyping(nextState.doneTyping);
    }
  }
```

Code:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      typing: true,
    };
    this.interval = null;
    this.handleTyping = this.handleTyping.bind(this);
  }

  handleTyping(doneTyping) {
    if (doneTyping) {
      this.setState({ typing: !this.state.typing });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.typing ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}</h3>
        <Typewriter text={"typewriter_testing"} typeSpeed={50} handleTyping={this.handleTyping}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Typewriter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      finalText: '',
      doneTyping: false,
    }
    this.typeWriter = this.typeWriter.bind(this);
  }

  typeWriter(text, n) {
    if (n < (text.length)) {
      if (n + 1 == (text.length)) {
        let j = text.substring(0, n+1);
        this.setState({ finalText: j, doneTyping: !this.state.doneTyping });
        n++;
      }
      else {
        let k = text.substring(0, n+1) + '|';
        this.setState({ finalText: k });
        n++;
      }
      setTimeout( () => { this.typeWriter(text, n) }, this.props.typeSpeed );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.typeWriter(this.props.text, 0);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.doneTyping && (nextState.doneTyping !== this.state.doneTyping)) {
      nextProps.handleTyping(nextState.doneTyping);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.finalText }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```